# Add class to DIV with TD Wrapping

Tags: jquery

Im trying to add a class to a TD which contains a DIV.

HTML:

```
<td>
  <div class="report">
    Some HTML
  </div>
</td>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.report').prev().addClass('wrapper');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think perhaps you're looking for `.parent()` and not `.prev()`

Answer (score 4):

`$('.report').parent().addClass('wrapper');`

Parent, not Prev :)

Answer (score 2):

`.prev()` searches only among siblings of the node, ie. nodes that reside on the same level of the DOM tree. The function you're looking for is `.parent()`.